# phpMyAdmin error on CentOS7 / nginx virtual box

Tags: nginx, centos

I been spending the past several days building a 'simple' LEMP virtual machine for web development.  I HAD phpMyAdmin 4.4 working fine using a symlink from /usr/share/phpMyAdmin -> www/site.com/pub_html/pma and a  sites-available/sites-enabled configuration. However, I thought 'whats the point in having the symlink when i could just move the entire phpMyAdmin directory to my pub_html folder...". So I moved it, deleted the symlink and now PMA is not accessible via the browser! I am getting a Connection Timeout error in browser.  I have restarted services nginx, php-fpm, mysqld, and have cleared cache in browser, restarted my VB.

If I move a directory that has been symlinked AND is essentially being used by server blocks in sites-enabled, do i have to REDO the sites-available/enabled configuration?

Any thoughts as to what the issue/problem might be?  Thanks for help!

Comment: did you restart nginx after deleting the symlink and moving the folder?

Comment: i did. In the end it was a typo in my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled directory: i had a symlink for pma instead of pma.conf. i was looking for *.conf files in my nginx.conf file. stupid oversight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was a typo in my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled directory: i had a symlink for pma instead of pma.conf. i was looking for *.conf files in my nginx.conf file. stupid oversight.